# Share an "identity" across tables

Tags: sql-server, database-design

I am working on a database that has an existing Individuals table that every user type derives from. In other words, there are tables like:
`Individual: FirstName, LastName, Email, <lots more>

    Employee: IndividualId

    Customer: IndividualId`

etc.

Now, I want to add new type of user (WeirdPerson) that does not derive from Individual. (WeirdPerson has significantly less data associated with it than any Individual, and I really don't want to set practically every field in Individual to null for a WeirdPerson.)

I need a key field to use on a table that will have entries from WeirdPersons and entries from Individuals. This suggests map tables like so: 
    `MashedupIndividuals: MashedupId, IndividualId

    MashedupWeirdPerson: MashedupId, WeirdPersonId`

I want MashedupId to be an auto-generated field. Since I'm using TSQL, an identity seems a good choice. Except that MashedupId is split across two tables. I considered yet another table: 
    `MashedupIds: MashedupId`
Set MashedupId to be an identity, and then make it a foreign key in MashedupIndividuals and MashedupWeirdPerson.

Is this the best way to proceed forward? How would you solve this?

EDIT: To clarify, the only piece of information I have for a WeirdPerson is an email address. I considered pulling the email field out of Individual, and then making a new GlobalPerson table with only GlobalPersonId and Email. The GlobalPerson table (or whatever better name I use) doesn't feel as natural as separating WeirdPerson as an entirely different type. However... I am willing to reconsider this position.

Comment: I guess I've never met someone with no first or last name. What exactly are these weirdpeople?

Comment: I edited my question to address the curious issue of the WeirdPerson. I figured I could get away without giving more information on them. I was, obviously, wrong. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest a table to host data common to all people in your application.  Then you could have additional tables for specific types of people and link them back to your common table.

tblPerson

- PersonID (pk)
- name, address, birthday, etc.

tblEmployee

- EmployeeID (pk)
- PersonID (fk to tblPerson)
- Title, OfficePhone, Email, etc.

tblCustomer

- CustomerID (pk)
- PersonID (fk to tblPerson)
- Other fields...

EDIT:

Here are some definitions more applicable to your question (and also more fun with these weird people).  The key is establishing the data that weird people and normal people share and then establishing the tables/relationships to support that model.  It might be necessary to move fields that are not applicable to weird people from tblIndividual to tblNormalPerson.

tblIndividual

- IndividualID (pk)
- Other fields for data applicable to both weird/normal people

tblWeirdPerson

- WeirdPersonID (pk)
- IndividualID (fk to tblIndividual)
- NumberOfHeads (applicable to weird people)

tblNormalPerson

- NormalPersonID (pk)
- IndividualID (fk to tblIndividual)
- FirstName (other fields applicable to normal people)
- LastName
- Etc...

Comment: Actually, the db already contains such a setup. The problem is that the WeirdPerson is not suitable for my Individuals table.

Comment: I think he means, you clearly don't have a base person class if you have a WeirdPerson class that "is not" a person.  You could have tblPerson, which WeirdPerson etc derive from, and tblDetailPerson, which the "normal" people derive from.  I think that's what mmayo's getting at.

Comment: Then you need to be more specific about what makes these people weird. They have no name or address? Or is the problem the person table has many more fields that don't apply?

Comment: This seems to be the best solution (even if I didn't initially like it). Thanks everyone for hashing the possibilities over with me.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `uniqueidentifier` field for your id.  This is guaranteed to be unique across multiple tables.  Use the [`NEWID()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa276822(SQL.80).aspx) function to generate new values.

Comment: +1: Just a refination: Using a single SEQUENCE for all the tables.

Answer (score 0):

You could have a table with three fields, one of which is always null:

MashedupId, IndividualId,WeirdPersonId

or with an ID field and ID type (individual/weird)

Comment: Yes, I considered that as well. In general though, I'm not a fan of such a solution. It's harder to query for what type a person is, and the NULL in every row irritates me.

Comment: You could have a table 'above' individual (shared) with just a sharedID and email (move the email field out of individual).  Then your mashup table just has mashedupID and sharedID.